# Events of .net class not raised in second appdomain

Tags: c#, .net, com, appdomain

Following Situation: A .Net4 WPF application is creating multiple appdomains on startup, launching the mainwindow in the first custom created appdomain, simulating a multiple instance behavior inside a single process, e.g. I´m able to start a second, third,... mainwindow where each will run in its own appdomain isolated from the others (lessons learned, that doesn´t affect native components)

```
AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("FancyAppDomainIdentifier");
appDomain.DoCallBack(() =>
       {
            var thread = new Thread(OnThreadStart);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
       });
```

Where OnThreadStart() is basically doing a

```
new App().Run();
```

where App is the Standard System.Windows.Application.

This has been working nicely so far, but now I have a third party component which is basically a .net wrapper for some com components interacting with some hardware. The wrapper component is raising events to relay hardware events (button pressed) but these events are not raised, if I register the eventhandler in the first custom created appdomain.

If I remove the [STAThread] attribute from the method responsible for creating the custom appdomains, making the first custom created appdomain the first thread running STA, the events get raised.

I´ve had issues with native components when running multiple windows using this setup, but since this is currently only one window and only one instance of the wrapper I´m stuck.

Comment: Does the native component create native threads and fire the events on these threads? There is no way for .NET to map these threads to appdomains and as far as I know the call is executed in the default/first appdomain of the process and the callback may simply fail as a result of this. You can try to debug your application using the native code debugger to discover if there are unexpected unhandled native exceptions.

Comment: Are you trying to handle the COM wrapper events across domains *and* across threads?

Comment: Not across threads and not across Domains (at least from the .net perspective)

Comment: What is the COM object's threading model in the registry (`Apartment`, `Free`, `Both`)? BTW, if replying, add @noseratio, otherwise I don't get notified.

Comment: @@noseratio: There are two com libraries involved, one is Apartment and the other one not set